# Chain inheritance java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

i'm trying to implement a help vehicles society

but i'm first focusing on the vehicle part 
a vehicle can be a HeadQuarter or a Machine

A Machine is then specified into a Support Vehicle ( SV) or a Emergency Vehicle (EV)

EV and SV both extends Machine which extends Vehicle

Machines are particular because they can transport people, so i defined in the machine Class, a method Embark( String) that stores the string in the arraylist which is an attribute of Machine Class.

Then i went into the Society implementation, a Society have an ArrayList of vehicles ( whichs can be either a Machine( that specify into an EV or SV) or an HQ) but when i try to embark people in a SV, i can't access the Machine Methods

i don't really understand why can someone explain me please ? Thank you very much

here is the Society.java

```
import Vehicle.*;
import Vehicle.machine.SupportVehicle;
import Vehicle.machine.EmergencyVehicle;
import Vehicle.machine.*;

public class Society {
private ArrayList <Vehicle> Vehicles;
public void AddVehicle(Vehicle V1){
    this.Vehicles.add(V1);
}

public Society(){
    this.Vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Society S;
    S = new Society();

    SupportVehicle SV;

    SV =  new SupportVehicle();

    Vehicle V1; 
    V1 = new Vehicle();
    S.AddVehicle(V1);
    S.Vehicles.get(0).embark("bar"); // Embark is a Machine Method but i can't access it  : " The method Embark(string) is undefined for the type Vehicle

}
```

}

Comment: Please show all the relevant code, and your main should be `main`,unless since specific environment requires `maint`.

Comment: And if you added `embark` to Machine, Vehicle won't be able to access it unless Vehicle extends Machine.

Comment: If `Machine extends Vehicle` and you have a `Vehicle` you cannot access `Machine` methods, because `Vehicle` is not a `Machine`. A `Machine` is-a `Vehicle`. Note: your code is confusing: `Vehicle` should extend `Machine` if we are following human logic.

Comment: "a vehicle can be a HeadQuarter" <- What? And the fact that you never mention HeadQuarter after that line makes it all the more confusing. As for the error: You said you defined the embark method in the Machine class  which extends Vehicle. So Vehicle has no embark methodand you would have to use a List<Machine> if you want to use the embark method.

Comment: Please provide the code of your other classes as well and make sure you compiled them correctly, i.e. are not using outdated code. Furthermore, the method in your error message is called `Embark()`, whereas you are calling `embark()`. Watch your naming. In Java, class names are usually capitalized, whereas method names and variables by convention start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: I would recommend thoroughly reviewing inheritance, as you seem to have some misconceptions about how it works.

Comment: This sounds like a great place to start learning about the Decorator design pattern. Even in this simple example, you are experiencing one of the shortcomings of preferring Inheritance over composition. Here's a decent explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this " so i defined in the machine Class, a method Embark( String)" and you want to access that method from a vehicle.

Machine extends Vehicle so Vehicle does not have access to the machine's methods.

A possible solution is to add that method to the Vehicle class.

Another solution is to have a private ArrayList  machines   instead of private ArrayList  Vehicles;

If you want to use ((Machine)S.Vehicles.get(0)).embark("bar"); you should first check the instance = "if S.Vehicles.get(0) instanceof Machine"

PS: the variables should start with lowercase =)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is, that you "look" at your object through a `Vehicle`-Class "glasses", because you want to call the method on `S.Vehicles.get(0)` and `Vehicles` is a List of type `Vehicle`. In this case you are able to see only functions of the `Vehicle`-Class. To see the methods of `Machine`-Class you need to cast the object to `Machine`-Class first:

```
((Machine)S.Vehicles.get(0)).embark("bar");
```

Comment: And that's how runtime exceptions are formed ;)

Comment: yeah, sure, he should check the type first :) but in this case it will work

Answer (score 0):

`embark( String str)` is a method defined in `Machine` class an not `Vehicle` class. The compiler does not know that `Society.Vehicles` contains instances of `Machine` Class as it could contain instances of Vehicle Class itself or that of other extensions.

1) If you know that all the Vehicle instances in Society would be Machine Instances than just change the type of vehicles as follows

```
private ArrayList <Machine> Vehicles;
```

2) If Above case is not true than following would help

```
if(S.Vehicles.get(0) instanceof Machine)
{
    ((Machine)S.Vehicles.get(0)).embark("Something");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys thank you all for your answers, i read them all and i figured out that the issue was a compilation issue, 
i added a method embark ( string n1) in vechile and i override it in machine, so that when i execute my code everything goes smooth

Comment: I think it would be nice if you set one of the answers given to "accepted answer".